# Do Intel HD 3000 Graphics run out of the box on Linux?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, intel-graphics, open-source

Do Intel HD 3000 Graphics run out of the box on Linux? Or do I have to do some manual work to get it working? Does Intel develop open source drivers?

Are they faster than on Windows?

This would apply for any Linux distribution.

Comment: Which distribution are you looking at?

Comment: Related article on that subject: [Intel Graphics On Linux Still Behind Windows, With Sandy Bridge](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_hd3000_winbuntu&num=1)

Comment: Any opinion would be great. Thanks, i will read it.

Comment: Please don't ask questions about opinions -- Super User is not a discussion forum. Answers should include facts and detailed references (see [FAQ])

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 beta seems to support the graphics drivers out of the box, as per this [discussion.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706846)

As an opinion for game, here's a quote from the same discussion

> I am getting stutter in some games, which are mainly in wine, or java (minecraft).